# Fiscal year from getdate in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to get the fiscal year from getdate(). My fiscal year format should be if getdate is today(18/03/2022) then the fiscal year column should show 'FY22'
I used the below query to get the fiscal year
Query Used:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0sxX.png)

Comment: Query Used: select 
CASE 
  WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) > 6 
   THEN YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1
   ELSE YEAR(GETDATE())
  END AS [FISCAL YEAR]

Comment: Welcome! Please post any code as *text*, not an image! See here for the many reasons why https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 6 months to the date (getdate in your example), then take the righmost two digits of the year, and concatenate 'FY' in front of it
The actual expression is rdbms dependent -you have not tagged; but for SQLServer:

```
'FY'+right(cast(year(dateadd(month,6,getdate())) as char(4)), 2)
```

or, using a relatively recent FORMAT function making use of format providers in the Microsoft .Net library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
select format(dateadd(month,6,getdate()),'\F\Yyy')
```

Backslash characters cause the function to ignore any special formatting code meaning of the letters F and Y, and hence F and Y are simply passed on to the output, the remaining yy is a format specifier for two digit years.

This is, of course, if your fiscal year runs from 1-Jul to 30-Jun.